# How to check if all numbers in a nested list are equal to n

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, rgb, mutation

So I want to encode a secret image in another b&w image. 
This image must have the same size as the original image that we are trying to hide the secret image in, so we have a correspondence of pixels for the two images.

To encode the secret image:

If a pixel in the secret image is white (so, with RGB values of [255, 255, 255]), add 1 to the blue component (last number).

Otherwise, leave the
blue component untouched.

So basically the coloured image is hidden in the b&w image by using an altered blue component from the original image.

*Decoding the b&w image is done through reversal of the encoding process.*

So lets say I currently have the following list of pixels:

```py
P = [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 184, 254], [255, 0, 254]]
```

Assuming that the width and height of both images are the same.

How would I check if any 'pixel' in P is equal to 255? So this means that all 3 numbers in the 'pixel' must be equal to 255.

Comment: To check if any pixel is `255 255 255` you can just use `in` : `[255, 255, 255] in P` which would evaluate to True.

Comment: Are you using lists or numpy arrays for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
for idx,lst in enumerate(P):
    if lst==[255,255,255]:
       print(idx,lst)
```

or

```
enc_P=[] 
for lst in P:
    if lst==[255,255,255]:
       print(lst)
    enc_P.append(lst)
```

Comment: How would I do this without using enumerate to iterate?

Comment: if you don't want the `index` of the pixel in `P`, which I think you need it. You can just use it without enumerate. If you still need the index then you may create another list enc_P=[] then iterate over `P` and append `lst` to enc_P after you modify the pixel. Hope that make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check if all values in inner list are equal to 255 and it will return index of the inner list in P:

```
P = [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 184, 254], [255, 0, 254]]
def checker(P):
    for subP in P:
        if subP[1:] == subP[:-1] and subP[0] == 255:
            return subP, P.index(subP)


checker(P)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` based approach would be the fastest.

using `numpy` you could do something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> P = np.array(P)
>>> np.all((P == 255), axis=1)
array([False,  True, False, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
P = [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 184, 254], [255, 0, 254]]

count = 0
for i in range(len(P)):
    for j in range(len(P[i])):
        if P[i][j] == 255:
            count += 1
    if count == 3:
        print(i)
    count = 0
```

this way you can find all indexes that contains specific values in a 2D list.

the code above prints 1 because only P in index 1 contains the list [255, 255, 255]